# How to suppress a warning from Checkmarx in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, suppress-warnings, checkmarx

After adding [*Jackson*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API)) as a dependency in my project, I get the warning:

> Provides transitive vulnerable dependency maven:com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.4 CVE-2022-42003 7.5 Deserialization of Untrusted Data vulnerability with medium severity found  Results powered by Checkmarx(c)

I appreciate the reminder provided by this message. But now that I am aware of this issue, I wish to suppress the message.

How can I suppress this message from appearing in my IDE (IntelliJ)?

Comment: You can invoke intention actions popup on your dependency and select `Suppress for tag`. E.g. https://prnt.sc/aGTpkP8RDCM2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring up the solution

1. Bring up the solution-wide analysis window.
2. Click on "Toolset, Environment" to show the warning.
3. Right-mouse on the warning.
4. Select "Ignore issue".
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable the "Package Checker" plugin to get rid of all such warnings